# Как изменить размер clip-path SVG?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, анимация

Я использую SVG в качестве маски для изображения, и  пытаюсь изменить  размер изображения.

Я изменил ширину и высоту (до 100), но изображение по-прежнему не масштабируется. Просто остается того же размера.

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJOXNZ)

Здесь мой SVG код:

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath">
      <path fill="#EDEBEA" d="M468.855,234.292H244.117V9.439L468.855,234.292z" />
      <path fill="#EDEBEA" d="M6.864,8.939h224.73v224.733L6.864,8.939z" />
      <path fill="#EDEBEA" d="M244.118,469.73V245.005h224.737L244.118,469.73z" />
      <path fill="#EDEBEA" d="M231.594,245.005V469.73H6.863L231.594,245.005z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to resize SVG clip-path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34064917/7394871) от участника  [@catandmouse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/511659/catandmouse).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/34064917/7394871

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Во-первых, когда вы устанавливаете атрибуты `width` и `height` на
  величину `100`, это делает svg  высотой и шириной `100px`. Если вы
  хотите, чтобы svg имела полную ширину, вам нужно установить 100% для
  ширины.
- Во-вторых,  вам нужно указать значение атрибута `viewbox`, чтобы
  получить масштабирование и систему координат для элементов вашего
  svg.

*Здесь пример для `viewbox="0 0 500 500"` и `width="30%"`*

```css
svg path {
fill:#EDEBEA;
}
#img1 {
height:500px;
width:500px;
clip-path:url(#svgPath);
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 500 500" width="30%" >
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath">
      <path  d="M468.855,234.292H244.117V9.439L468.855,234.292z" />
      <path  d="M6.864,8.939h224.73v224.733L6.864,8.939z" />
      <path  d="M244.118,469.73V245.005h224.737L244.118,469.73z" />
      <path  d="M231.594,245.005V469.73H6.863L231.594,245.005z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image id="img1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DR2G.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="500" width="500"/>
</svg>
```

Теперь увеличим размер в два раза: `<svg viewbox="0 0 500 500" width="60%" >`

```css
svg path {
fill:#EDEBEA;
}
#img1 {
height:500px;
width:500px;
clip-path:url(#svgPath);
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 500 500" width="60%" >
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath">
      <path  d="M468.855,234.292H244.117V9.439L468.855,234.292z" />
      <path  d="M6.864,8.939h224.73v224.733L6.864,8.939z" />
      <path  d="M244.118,469.73V245.005h224.737L244.118,469.73z" />
      <path  d="M231.594,245.005V469.73H6.863L231.594,245.005z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image id="img1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DR2G.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="500" width="500"/>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34066282/7394871) от участника  [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

### Примеры анимации clip-path

**Горизонтальное смещение**

Для этого используем команду анимации смещения по горизонтали:
 `<animate attributeName="x" values="0;450;450;0;0" begin="click" dur="10s" restart="whenNotActive" />`

`values="0;450;450;0;0"` перечисление позиций горизонтальной координаты "x"

Одинаковые цифры - `450;450` обеспечивают паузу нахождения в этой позиции

`restart="whenNotActive` защита от повторного запуска анимации

*Запуск анимации - клик по фигуре*

```css
svg path {
fill:#EDEBEA;
}
#img1 {
height:500px;
width:500px;
clip-path:url(#svgPath);
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 500 500" width="40%" >
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath">
      <path  d="M468.855,234.292H244.117V9.439L468.855,234.292z" />
      <path  d="M6.864,8.939h224.73v224.733L6.864,8.939z" />
      <path  d="M244.118,469.73V245.005h224.737L244.118,469.73z" />
      <path  d="M231.594,245.005V469.73H6.863L231.594,245.005z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image id="img1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOhFs.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="500" width="500">
  
  <animate attributeName="x" values="0;450;450;0;0" begin="click" dur="10s" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </image>
</svg>
```

**Вертикальное смещение**

Для этого используем команду анимации смещения по вертикали:

`<animate attributeName="y" values="0;450;450;0;0;-460;-460;0" begin="click" dur="10s" restart="whenNotActive" />`

```css
svg path {
fill:#EDEBEA;
}
#img1 {
height:500px;
width:500px;
clip-path:url(#svgPath);
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 500 500" width="40%" >
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath">
      <path  d="M468.855,234.292H244.117V9.439L468.855,234.292z" />
      <path  d="M6.864,8.939h224.73v224.733L6.864,8.939z" />
      <path  d="M244.118,469.73V245.005h224.737L244.118,469.73z" />
      <path  d="M231.594,245.005V469.73H6.863L231.594,245.005z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image id="img1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DR2G.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="500" width="500">
  
  <animate attributeName="y" values="0;450;450;0;0;-460;-460;0" begin="click" dur="10s" restart="whenNotActive" />
  </image>
</svg>
```